# Javascript validate form OR function

Tags: javascript, validation

I am trying to ask the user to input at least 1 of the options. From my codes the user need to input all the inputs. Can anyone please check what is wrong with my code?

**jsp**

```
<form role="form" method="POST" id="search" action="Servlet" 
      onsubmit="return validateForm();">

    <label>Name</label> 
    <input name="name">

    <label>ID</label> 
    <input name="id">

    <label>no</label> 
    <input name="no">

    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

**javascript**

```
function validateForm() {
    var name = document.forms["search"]["name"].value;
    var id = document.forms["search"]["id"].value;
    var no = document.forms["search"]["no"].value;

    if ( (name == null || name == "") || (id == null || id == "") || (no == null && no == "")) {
        alert("Please enter either one to perform search");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your HTML also

Comment: Look your condition: if name is empty OR if id is empty OR no... so if one of those fields is empty it won't continue

Comment: @Sergio I put the html codes. Please take a look. Thanks!

Comment: You have a typo on the  onsubmit, there is an h too much. Also, if you don't use strict comparison you can just use `if (!name && !id && !no) {...}` except if 0 is valid though

Comment: Textbox values can not be null so that is a waste of a check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function validateForm() {
    var name = document.forms["search"]["name"].value;
    var id = document.forms["search"]["id"].value;
    var no = document.forms["search"]["no"].value;

    if ( (name == null || name == "") && (id == null || id == "") && (no == null || no == "")) {
        alert("Please enter either one to perform search");
        return false;
    }
}
```

or you would do it as @isherwood did. also take care of typos like not closing your input tag
should goes like this `<input name="no"/>` good luck and I hope this would help

Answer (score 1):

Just a little logic adjustment should do the trick:

```
if ( 
    (name != null || name != "") || 
    (id != null || id != "") || 
    (no != null && no != "") 
) {
```

This is saying that if any one of the fields has a value, continue.

Comment: why you do the parenthesis thing?! you shouldn't group since you're ORing all the cases ;)

Comment: I didn't. The OP did. I just reversed the logic.